# Word representation in Graphics

Tags: logo, information-graphics, line-art, symbols

Does anyone know of a good repository where words are represented as symbols/graphics. So for example, a cycle is represented as a line sketch of a cycle and a boat as a drawing of a boat. I am not from a graphics background so perhaps I am not using the right lingo, but I hope I am able to communicate the question.

I am looking for what are the best pictorial representation of words like debt, equity, loans, financial returns etc. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to look up your keywords (debt, equity, etc) into an icon database, like:

- https://www.thenounproject.com/
- https://www.flaticon.com/
- https://www.iconbros.com/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for but cannot find representation for words like company equity. Its very specific. What kind of designers usually illustrate words as icons ?

Comment: Well some definitions are more abstract than others and this is a challenge in infographics. For instance its easier to find an icon for a physical object, like a KEY, than an icon for an intangible concept like equity.